# Can't fix the padding

Tags: css, html

I am working on a site. I want the big image(900px width ) to cover whole of its container . At the moment there is a bit padding towrds the right which I am unable to fix. Please help me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="index-page" class="canvas canvastext no-touch draganddrop rgba borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity fontface video audio localstorage mobile-768 mozilla wordpress-section w-900 lt-960 js gradient rgba opacity textshadow multiplebgs boxshadow borderimage borderradius no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransitions fontface not-ie domloaded" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<head>
<body id="home" class="home blog">
<div id="wrap" style="">
<header role="banner">
<section id="site-logo">
<a href="http://ackmaster.com/wordpress">
<img width="1200px" alt="Ackmaster.com" src="http://ackmaster.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/WebSiteMain2.jpg">
</a>
</section>
<section id="nav-wrap">
</header>
<div id="content" role="main">
<footer style="min-height: 0; padding-top: 0;" role="contentinfo">
</div>
<script>
<div id="fancybox-tmp"></div>
<div id="fancybox-loading">
<div id="fancybox-overlay"></div>
<div id="fancybox-wrap">
</body>
</html>
```

Using firebug the related CSS is:

```
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    color: #8E8E8E;
}
dark.css (line 7)
body {
    background-image: url("bg-base.jpg");
}
dark.css (line 6)
body {
    min-width: 480px;
}
mobile.css (line 6)
body {
    background: url("../images/bg-base.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
layout.css (line 7)
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    color: #3F3F3F;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
}
boilerplate.css (line 37)
body {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin: 0;
}
boilerplate.css (line 35)
Inherited fromhtml#index-page.canvas
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
boilerplate.css (line 33)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style sheet "layout.css" has `padding: 0 30;` for the div with id `#wrap`. That's the div your image is sitting in. The padding affects left and right side of the image. Set it to `padding-left: 30px;` to keep the left padding and remove the right.

Comment: This looks intentional though? Perhaps he needs to just make the #site-logo img {width: 100%}. Also the wrap seems to be missing the margin:auto at full-size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body id="home" class="home blog" style="margin: 0px;">
```

You need to change the margin of the body to 0px using CSS.